# Esconder botões ao imprimir, usando window.print()

Tags: css

Tenho uma listagem aonde o usuário consegue imprimir através do `window.print()`, porém está aparecendo os 2 botões que possui na pagina.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**É possivel eu "esconder" esses bottões através do CSS, na hora da impressão?**

**BUTTONS**

```
<div>
<a href="listagem_cliente.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Voltar</button></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.print();return false"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" title="Imprimir">Imprimir</button></a>
 /div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Consegui aqui!**

CSS

```
<style>
@media print { 
#noprint { display:none; } 
body { background: #fff; }
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="noprint">
<a href="listagem_cliente.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Voltar</button></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.print();return false"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" title="Imprimir">Imprimir</button></a>
</div>
```